# Using SSL Certificate for both deployed application and Istio Ingress in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, serverless, istio

I have deployed an aioquic server application to Kubernetes cluster. This server requires certificate as configuration to start it. I also have an Istio ingress associated with my cluster for outside communication. Is it possible to have SSL cert for both Ingress as well as deployed application? If so, can we use the same SSL cert for both or it should be seperate certs?

Comment: do you have cert-manager already deployed?

Comment: @Adiii Currently I'm having self signed certificate.

Comment: so why not going for cert-manager and its free, all you need domain

Comment: https://cert-manager.io/

Comment: I can try that as well it is not an issue. But what Im looking for here is, is it possible to use the same certificate for both ingress as well as the deployed server application

Comment: yes, once you have the certs then you can use that. but why you need the tls for application when you can mtls at istio level

Comment: https://www.jetstack.io/blog/cert-manager-istio-integration/

Comment: That is the requirement of my server application. It needs certificate as part of its configuration